# Union of two ideals is ideal iff either of the one ideal is subset of another

Tags: ring-theory

Let I1 and I2 be any ideals of Ring R Then, prove that I1 union I2 is ideal of R iff either I1 is subset of I2  Or I2 is subset of I1.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, union of two generic ideals is not an ideal if there is no containment. One direction is obvious since you are considering just one ideal. The opposite direction is:
Consider two elements w $\in I $, v $\in J$ such that these elements don’t belong to the intersection of the two ideals. Then v+w must belong to I or J and you verify so that it is impossible, if you suppose for example that v+w $\in I$ you get v+w-w $\in I $ a contraddiction.